# what's the regex for removing everything after the last / if it starts with this

Tags: regex

Can you help me with the regex for deleting everything at the end of a string, if the end of the string start with ?_t_id=

ie:

```
domain.it/antioxidanter/?_t_id=187
domain.it/animaliska/?_t_id=211
```

Comment: `(?<=\/)[^\/]*$` https://regex101.com/r/fM4nI8/1

Answer (score 1):

Search:

```
\?_t_id=\d+$
```

replace with:

```
empty string
```

Since `?` is a special character, you need to escape that in-order to match a literal `?` symbol. In js,

```
string.replace(/\?_t_id=\d+$/m, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

To match the part you want to remove (replace by empty string), use

```
/\/\?_t_id=(?!.*\/).*/
```

This will match (bold):

- domain.it/antioxidanter/**?_t_id=187**

---

To match the part you want to keep, to (re-)assign it to a variable, use

```
/(.+(?=\?_t_id=.*))|.+(?!\?_t_id=.*)/
```

This will match (bold):

- **domain.it/antioxidanter/**?_t_id=187
- **domain.it/animaliska/any_id=211**